# How does one downcast a std::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, downcast

Consider:

```
struct SomethingThatsABase
{
    virtual bool IsChildOne() const { return false; }
    virtual bool IsChildTwo() const { return false; }
};

struct ChildOne : public SomethingThatsABase
{
    virtual bool IsChildOne() const { return true; }
};

struct ChildTwo : public SomethingThatsABase
{
    virtual bool IsChildTwo() const { return true; }
};

void SomeClientExpectingAChildOne(std::shared_ptr<ChildOne> const& ptrOne)
{
    //Does stuff
}

void SomeClient(std::shared_ptr<SomethingThatsABase> const& ptr)
{
    if (ptr->IsChildOne())
    {
        SomeClientExpectingAChildOne(ptr); //Oops.
        //Hmm.. can't static_cast here, because we need a `shared_ptr` out of it.
    }
}
```

(Note that I can't simply do a `std::shared_ptr<ChildOne>(static_cast<ChildOne*>(ptr.get()))`, because then the reference counts don't get shared between the two `shared_ptr`s)

Answer (score 119, accepted):

This ought to work:

```
if (ptr->IsChildOne())
{
    SomeClientExpectingAChildOne(std::static_pointer_cast<ChildOne>(ptr));
}
```

Comment: Perfect! +1. (And probably the "green bent angle thing" soon too)

Comment: +1 - I wasn't aware of `std::static_pointer_cast`! How does this work, does the returned `shared_ptr` act like a proxy so that the two shared pointers maintain the same reference count or so?

Comment: @Frerich: A `shared_ptr` has two pointers -- one to the shared object, and one to the block with the strong and weak reference counts. Two `shared_ptr`s of different type can share the strong and weak reference count blocks without difficulty. My guess is that it's implemented with `static_pointer_cast` being a `friend` of `shared_ptr`, but of course your implementation may vary.

Comment: I've always used `shared_dynamic_cast` in Boost. Apparently `dynamic_pointer_cast` is more generic, however, because it works with various different types of pointers (`shared_ptr`, raw pointers, `intrusive_ptr`, and potentially anything else in the future).

Comment: @FrerichRaabe, @billy-oneal, probably it uses the `aliasing constructor`, (ref, ptr) create a shared_pointer copy of `ref` but pointing to `ptr`.

Answer (score 47):

The `shared_ptr` equivalent of `static_cast` is `static_pointer_cast`, and the `shared_ptr` equivalent of `dynamic_cast` is `dynamic_pointer_cast`.

Comment: I was unaware of both of these, so I went looking for some [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#static_pointer_cast). Cool stuff!

Answer (score 29):

Starting from C++11, §20.10.2.2.9 ([[util.smartptr.shared.cast]](http://eel.is/c++draft/util.smartptr.shared.cast)) of the C++ standard specifies the equivalents of `static_cast`, `const_cast` and `dynamic_cast` for `std::shared_ptr` to be as follows:

### `std::static_pointer_cast`:

```
template <class T, class U>
shared_ptr<T> static_pointer_cast(shared_ptr<U> const & r) noexcept;
```

`static_pointer_cast` requires `static_cast<T *>(r.get())` to be well formed. If `r` is empty, an empty `shared_ptr<T>` is returned, otherwise returns a pointer `w` sharing ownership with `r` where `w.get() == static_cast<T *>(r.get())` and `w.use_count() == r.use_count()`.

### `std::const_pointer_cast`:

```
template <class T, class U>
shared_ptr<T> const_pointer_cast(shared_ptr<U> const & r) noexcept;
```

`const_pointer_cast` has similar requirements and semantics to `static_pointer_cast`, except that `const_cast` is used instead of `static_cast`.

### `std::dynamic_pointer_cast`:

```
template <class T, class U>
shared_ptr<T> dynamic_pointer_cast(shared_ptr<U> const & r) noexcept;
```

`dynamic_pointer_cast` is a bit different as it requires `dynamic_cast<T *>(r.get())` to be well formed and have well defined semantics. If `dynamic_cast<T *>(r.get())` is a non-zero value, returns a pointer `w` sharing ownership with `r` where `w.get() == dynamic_cast<T *>(r.get())` and `w.use_count() == r.use_count()`, otherwise an empty `shared_ptr<T>` is returned.

### `std::reinterpret_pointer_cast`:

For C++17, [N3920](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3920.html) (adopted into Library Fundamentals TS [in February 2014](https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/02/trip-report)) also proposed a `std::reinterpret_pointer_cast` similar to the above, which would only require `reinterpret_cast<T *>((U *) 0)` to be well formed and returns `shared_ptr<T>(r, reinterpret_cast<typename shared_ptr<T>::element_type *>(r.get()))`. Note N3920 also changed the wording for the other `shared_ptr` casts and extended `shared_ptr` to support arrays.