# Is there a way to cast shared_ptr<void> to shared_ptr<T>?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, void-pointers, reference-counting

I want to keep the smart behavior of `std::shared_ptr`. So is there a way to cast a shared void pointer to another type while without confusing the reference counting? I can't get the raw pointer and create a new shared pointer from it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795629/how-does-one-downcast-a-stdshared-ptr

Comment: @BillyONeal: No, `void` is not a base class of all types. C++ isn't that pure OO.

Comment: @MSalters: that's why I wrote the comment rather than actual voting to close (I did not want want to do that unilaterally)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the pointer casts from [rob mayoff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25858963/82320); but be careful. It is easy to unintentionally trigger undefined behavior here:

```
struct MyClass {};

void* rawPtr = new MyClass;
shared_ptr<void> exampleVoid(rawPtr); // Undefined behavior;
                                      // calls delete (void*)ptr;

shared_ptr<void> exampleVoidCons(new MyClass);
    // OK, calls shared_ptr<void>::shared_ptr<MyClass>(MyClass*) which
    // makes a deleter calling delete (MyClass*)ptr;

shared_ptr<MyClass> example(new MyClass); // OK, calls delete (MyClass*)ptr;

shared_ptr<void> castToVoid = static_pointer_cast<void>(example);
    // OK, shared_ptr's deleter is erased so this still calls delete (MyClass*)ptr;
```

Typically this undefined behavior will result in the type's destructor not being called. For example, [see the output on ideone](http://ideone.com/w1qznT) and note that the version put into a `void*` never prints that it was destroyed.

---

See C++11 5.3.5 [expr.delete]/3:

> In the first alternative (delete object), if the static type of the object to be deleted is different from its dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the object to be deleted and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined.

Since the actual object will never have a dynamic type `void`, and `void` is never a base class of a dynamic type, `delete`ing a `void*` triggers undefined behavior.

Comment: A previous version of this answer had an incorrect `shared_ptr exampleVoid(new MyClass)` portion which I have now fixed. Feel free to remove upvotes for putting my foot in my mouth :P

Comment: +1 for providing a more complete answer, also recognizing you made a mistake, admitting and fixing it should be encouraged, most of us are here to learn and that is part of the process.

Comment: I'm cross because you deleted the answer for editing just as I was writing a comment regarding the incorrect example ;-)

Comment: @Steve: Stole your thunder did I? :)

Answer (score 23):

You can use [`std::static_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) or [`std::dynamic_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) depending on what kind of cast you want.