# C++ Multiple Dispatch

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, multiple-dispatch

Given following problem:

```
class Instrument {
};

class Guitar : public Instrument {
  public:
    void doGuitar() const;
};

class Piano : public Instrument {
  public:
    void doPiano() const;
};
```

I got a list of pointers to `Instrument`

```
list<shared_ptr<Instrument>> instruments;
```

in which i add instruments via (for example)

```
Guitar myGuitar;
instruments.push_back(make_shared<Guitar>(myGuitar));
```

Now, I want to iterate over the list `instruments` and call `doPiano()` iff the current instrument is a piano and `doGuitar()` iff it is a guitar. These two functions differ a lot and thus, cannot be made abstract in class `Instrument`.

The problem is that C++ won't be able to identify the type of the  `Instrument` by runtime, isn't it (due to single dispatch)? How can I achieve that it calls the piano- or the guitar-function depending on the current type the iterator is pointing at.

I would be happy if I could implement sth. working like this pseudo-code:

```
list<shared_ptr<Instrument>>::const_iterator it;
if ("current type == Guitar")
  (*it)->doGuitar();
else if ("current type == Piano")
  (*it)->doPiano();
```

**Result**

Actually, I ran into several problems with my approach. I did much refactoring using this post: [How does one downcast a std::shared_ptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795629/how-does-one-downcast-a-stdshared-ptr) . Thanks to all for your help :)

Comment: Why not simply have a virtual `do` function that does the right thing?

Comment: have a look at `std::dynamic_pointer_cast`. Then rip up your design and start again. Polymorphism is only suitable when all derived classes can reasonably share the same interface.

Comment: Actually, my example is just a small piece of my "real" implementation. There are several pure virtual functions in `Instrument`. I should have mentioned it.

Comment: Since you mention multiple dispatch you might want to take a look at the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#C.2B.2B_example).

Comment: "These two functions differ a lot and thus, cannot be made abstract in class Instrument." Show real code. As it stands now, do_piano and do_guitar are exactly the same and should be made a common pure virtual function in Instrument. You need a compelling argument to the contrary.

Answer (score 3):

The design can probably be improved to eliminate this problem, but working within the existing design you can add a virtual member function `Instrument::play_it` that takes a `Player` as polymorphic argument. In `Player` have two functions `play_guitar` (taking guitar argument) and `play_piano` (taking piano argument). In guitar class override `play_it` to call `Player::play_guitar` with self as argument. In piano class override `play_it` to call `Player::play_piano` with self as argument. Look ma no casts.

This isn't exactly multiple dispatch, it's known as the visitor pattern. However it's perhaps best to not focus too much on that, lest you start to name things `visitor` or such non-descriptive folly.

Answer (score 0):

A double dispatch works like this (pseudocode, important but trivial stuff omitted):

```
struct InstrumentVisitor{
   // knows all instruments
   virtual void doGuitar(Guitar*) = 0;
   virtual void doPiano(Piano*) = 0;
};

class Instrument {
   virtual void doInstrument(InstrumentVisitor*) = 0;
   ...
 };

class Piano : public Instrument {
    void doInstrument (InstrumentVisitor* v) {
       v->doPiano(this);
};

class Guitar : public Instrument {
    void doInstrument (InstrumentVisitor* v) {
       v->doGuitar(this);
};
```

Now we can devise concrete visitors.

```
struct Player : InstrumentVisitor {
  // does vastly different things for guitar and piano
   void doGuitar (Guitar* g) {
      g->Strum(pick, A6);
   }
   void doPiano (Piano* p) {
      p->Scale (Am, ascending);
};
```

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf For not having to write `*this` which can be really confusing at times. But it''s a matter of taste. Use references or pointers, I won't object.

Answer (score 0):

Type erasure is another option:

```
std::vector<std::function<void()>> playInstrument;
playInstrument.emplace_back([g = Guitar{}]() { return g.doGuitar(); });
playInstrument.emplace_back([p = Piano{} ]() { return p.doPiano();  });

playInstrument[0]();
```

For this you even don't need a common base class.

Answer (score -2):

One way to identify classes at runtime is to use `dynamic_cast`. But to use that, you need to have atleast one virtual method in your class. An empty virtual method can be added to the instrument class for that purpose.

```
class Instrument {
  private:
    virtual void emptyMethod_doNotCall() {} // Add this method.
};

class Guitar : public Instrument {
  public:
    void doGuitar() const;
};

class Piano : public Instrument {
  public:
    void doPiano() const;
};
```

The object type can be checked by doing a `dynamic_cast` to the target class pointer. `dynamic_cast` returns `NULL` if the object cannot be cast to the desired target class.

```
list<shared_ptr<Instrument>>::const_iterator it;
if (dynamic_cast<Guitar*>(it) != NULL)
  (*it)->doGuitar();
else if (dynamic_cast<Piano*>(it) != NULL)
  (*it)->doPiano();
```

Comment: each time a new instrument is added, you need to go over all of the code, add manually the case of this new instrument... why bother with a class hierarchy then?

Comment: Why not just make the destructor `virtual`? After all, since you're storing by base pointer it going to need to be.

Comment: @UmNyobe: The OP says "These two functions differ a lot and thus, cannot be made abstract in class Instrument". That's the reason I suggested doing a dynamic cast.

Comment: Dynamic cast in a pattern like this is your last resort when you need to save a failed design by 09:00 today, and it's 7:55 and you have had 3 hours of sleep during the last week.

Comment: Trying this method, leads to following compiler error: `cannot dynamic_cast 'it' (of type 'struct _list_const_iterator<shared_ptr<Instrument>>'') to type 'class Guitar*' (source is not a pointer)`.